# Print two-dimensional array with a function

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
void printBoard(int board[8][8])
{
int i,j;
for(i = 0; i<8; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<8; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

int main(){
int i, j;
    int board[8][8];

    for(i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<8; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &board[i][j]);
        }
    }

 printBoard(board);
```

Why does the following void function not print the two dimensional array? It just continues asking for input. I tried it without the function as well, and it still doesn't work.

We were meant to use this as part of our homework assignment. Can someone please explain how to get around this?

Comment: Inside the main function, you have `scanf`, which will ask for input 64 times for all the elements of the 2 dimensional array `board[8][8]`

Comment: How many arguments had you given your program ?

Comment: Don't use **magic numbers** (serach for it - in programming context). As youi notice, it is error-prone. Pass the lengths of the dimensions to the function and pass a VLA, not fixed-width array. Alternatively stick with the fixed-width array, but use constant-like macros for the dimensions! You should have learned that long before this exercise. If not, ask your teacher (if he does not know, he's a bad teacher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` is looping through `scanf` which is a function that asks for user input 64 times. You need to input 64 values before the `printBoard()` statement is reached.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your printBoard function doesn't print all array.
When you fix this (first loop in function 8 instead of 2) you get what you want but i suggest try on smaller array, since you need to put 64 values.

Answer (score 0):

In nested loops, the inner loop will execute to completion for every time that the outer loop executes. This means that `scanf` will be called 8 * 8 = 64 times. `scanf` takes an input from the console, so that means you will have to input 64 values into the console before they are printed.

Maybe try reducing the size of the array from 8 * 8 to something more manageable, like 3 * 3 or 4 * 4 -- that way you don't have to spend a minute or two punching in numbers just to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void printBoard(int board[8][8]);

int main(){
int i, j;
int board[8][8];

     for(i = 0; i<8; i++)
     {
     for(j = 0; j<8; j++)
     {
        scanf("%d", &board[i][j]);
     }
 }
  return 0; 
}
    void printBoard(int board[8][8])
      {
    int i,j;
  for(i = 0; i<8; i++)
  {
   for(j = 0; j<8; j++)
  {
    printf("%d ", board[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 }
  }
```

In your `i` for loop it is row and `j` loop is column so loop will 8 row and 8 columns so it will run 64 times, then it take 64 inputs and after scanf will complete.

Answer (score -1):

So I was inputting my values like this to begin with:

00000000 
00100000 
00001000 
00001010 
01010000 
00020000 
00000000 
00000000

Which didn't seem to work. 
Then, I tried:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

and it worked. I guess it counted 64 individual values this way. 
Thanks!